# Stored Procedure Select data from Server A and Insert data to Server B

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I would like to ask about how to write the Stored Procedure Select data from Server A and Insert data to Server B?

Comment: No differently to any other `PROCEDURE` with an `INSERT` in it; you'll just be using 4 part naming for your source object (`LinkedServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName`) instead of 2 part naming (`SchemaName.TableName`).

Answer (score 0):

1 . Create a linked server using steps at below link
https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/

2. Create a synonym for the table from the linked server you are going to use if there is only one table otherwise create synonym for that server so you dont have to use the complete name and if the server changes in future you dont have to go and change in every procedure instead you can just change the synonym.

   ```
    CREATE SYNONYM MySyn 
    FOR LinkedServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName;  
    GO
   ```
3. Use the synonym in your query to fetch the data.

   ```
    create procedure procedureName 
    as  
    begin 
    insert into destDB.schema.tablename select * from mysyn.sourcetablename
    end
   ```